# Why do I get the error "wrong number of type arguments" when I use hyper::Client in my method signature?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, hyper

I want to get a `hyper::Client` configured according to the URL scheme. For that, I created a small method:

```
extern crate http; // 0.1.8
extern crate hyper; // 0.12.7
extern crate hyper_tls; // 0.1.4

use http::uri::Scheme;
use hyper::{Body, Client, Uri};
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Feed;

impl Feed {
    fn get_client(uri: Uri) -> Client {
        match uri.scheme_part() {
            Some(Scheme::HTTP) => Client::new(),
            Some(Scheme::HTTPS) => {
                let https = HttpsConnector::new(4).expect("TLS initialization failed");
                let client = Client::builder().build::<_, Body>(https);
            }
            _ => panic!("We don't support schemes other than HTTP/HTTPS"),
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get this error message:

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected at least 1, found 0
  --> src/main.rs:13:32
   |
13 |     fn get_client(uri: Uri) -> Client {
   |                                ^^^^^^ expected at least 1 type argument
```

I don't understand why it doesn't compile since

- I've declared my use of the hyper crate in my main.rs
- I declare my use in file header

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [documentation for `Client`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.12.8/hyper/client/struct.Client.html): `Client` is a [generic type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-01-syntax.html) which depends on two type parameters: a connector type `C` and an optional body type `B`. You would need to specify which type parameters apply to the `Client` that you return, except that in your specific case it looks like you want to return either a `Client<HttpConnector>` or a `Client<HttpsConnector>` depending on the URI scheme. You can't do that, period.

Depending on how you intend to use your `get_client` function, you can wrap the return value in an `enum`:

```
enum MyClient {
    HttpClient (Client<HttpConnector>),
    HttpsClient (Client<HttpsConnector>),
}
impl MyClient {
    pub fn get(&self, uri: Uri) -> ResponseFuture {
        match self {
            HttpClient (c) => c.get (uri),
            HttpsClient (c) => c.get (uri),
        }
    }
}

fn get_client(uri: Uri) -> MyClient { /* … */ }
```

or you can define a trait, implement it for `Client<HttpConnector>` and `Client<HttpsConnector>` and have `get_client` return a boxed instance of your trait, something like:

```
trait MyClient {
    pub fn get(&self, uri: Uri) -> ResponseFuture;
}
impl<C> MyClient for Client<C> {
    pub fn get(&self, uri: Uri) -> ResponseFuture {
        Client<C>::get (&self, uri)
    }
}

fn get_client(uri: Uri) -> Box<MyClient> { /* … */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

[`hyper::Client`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.12.8/hyper/client/struct.Client.html) takes type parameters. You can omit them in the associated function call `Client::new()` because the compiler will deduce them, but it won't do that in the function signature.

You want the return type to be `Client<HttpConnector, Body>`.

The problem with that is that your builder method returns a `Client<HttpsConnector, Body>`, which is different. You might have to define your own trait to abstract over the connector.